# Google App Engine version URL and app Versioning

Tags: android, google-app-engine

When you upload a new version to app engine, let's call it '10', you can send requests to this version directly using this url: http://10.myapp.appspot.com

I find it very useful and I made an habit to release my android app pointing to the corresponding server version. So when I upload version 10 to the play store it points to http://10.myapp.appspot.com, the same goes to version 9: http://9.myapp.appspot.com.

**Is this correct usage or this feature? What is the best practices regarding Versioning in App Engine?**

I'm doing it because I want to maintain backward compatibility, so that if I'm making a change in the server the old clients won't notice it because they are connected to an older version.

I understand it's problematic because all the versions share the same DB as well as problems that could occur when I configure warmup for the default version that doesn't apply to the other versions. **So am I making a mistake by using it this way?**

Comment: apart from anything else, this might be slightly more expensive as I imagine an instance set per version served would be needed, rather then all requests sharing all instances.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But this bothers me less then errors a user might get when I upgrade my server and he still has an old version of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application versions are useful for things like testing new versions before deploying them "live." I would not use it to ensure backward compatibility with you existing clients. Furthermore you can have only limited number of versions per application.

> You can have up to ten versions of each application; once you've reached that limit, you'll need to delete existing versions before you can deploy new ones.

Another thing to consider is that some App Engine services (e.g. Datastore) are independent on a particular version but others (e.g. Cron jobs) are tight to a concrete version (usually default version unless specified otherwise).

However, you can have different versions of your application's public interface (REST/SOAP services or whatever you use) so that new features or changes are available only to the respective clients.

Here is an example of dummy REST API using versions.

```
https://myapp.com/api/v1/questions/10/answers?max=10

https://myapp.com/api/v2/questions/10/latest-10-answers
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Ten versions doesn't bother me because I believe that users will update the app, but, that's a good point in case someone really doesn't want to update or is unable. Any more ideas why you think it's a bad practice?

Comment: I added another thing to consider.

Comment: Yeah it's a good consideration, but I can specify a specific version for the cron job, so that solved this problem. I'm using a shared library between android and the java server and I have the version constant, so I can just pass that to the cron job (although I never used cron job, so I'm not sure).

Comment: I really like the API versioning, I think I might adapt that

Comment: Great. Anyway if it helped you to solve your problem, mark the answer as accepted so that others can benefit.

Comment: Sure! Thanks! Just want to make sure it's the path I'm taking and how I'm going implement it in the server. Perhaps you have a suggestion for API versioning using Spring?

Comment: Basically you can implement different controllers per resource and version (e.g. `QuestionsControllerV1` with URI `/api/v1/questions` and `QuestionsControllerV2` with URI `/api/v2/questions`). But I believe that you may find another solution.

Comment: After considerations it seems to be too much over head to do that. Also, because I'm on app engine, it will add a lot of complexity to the instance startup, which is crucial. I ended up forcing my users to update when a new version breaks old versions.

Comment: Anyways, I realized, thanks to you, that it's not a wise idea to do what I was doing with the versions :) So from now on all the my users connect to http://myapp.appspot.com and not to http://10.myapp.appspot.com. THANKS!